# How to check if any words in a list contain a partial string?

Tags: c#

```
    var list=alist.Contains("somestring")
```

this matches whole string, how to see if any word in list has a substring matching "somestring"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method:

```
bool contained = alist.Any( l => l.Contains("somestring") );
```

This is checking each element using [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx), which checks substrings.  You previously were using [`ICollection<string>.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx), which checks for a specific element of the list.

Comment: what if you also want the other way,  the result when the list item is a substring of "somestring".

Comment: Just use:  alist.Any(l => "somestring".Contains(l) );

Answer (score -1):

```
var hasPartialMatch = alist.Split(' ').ToList()
      .Any(x => x.Contains("somestring"));
```

Comment: If alist is a "list" (in the wording of the question), there's no need for Split(' ')